# Is it possible to set the number of lines per form in a .ppd file

Tags: printing, linux-device-driver, cups

I have a Ubuntu Server with CUPS installed. We have an old IBM InfoPrint 6500 Printer that I have set up in Cups and can successfully print to it from CUPS. I am printing to a 14x11 Greenbar paper with the margins and page size set correctly. The default Form number of lines per page is set to 66, the issue I am having is that when I print to it from CUPS the number of lines gets changed from 66 to 49.

As far as CUPS is concerned that is not a big deal, anything printed to it from CUPS fits the page just fine. The issue is that we have a AS400 that also prints to the same printer and it will only print 49 lines per page instead of the default 66. If I turn the printer off and back on, the number of lines changes back to the default 66 and the AS400 can print to it just fine. But when something is printed to it from CUPS, the default is changed back to 49. I've looked inside the .ppd file I am using in CUPS and cannot find anywhere to adjust that value. I've also looked to see if there is a setting in Ghostscript that might be able to adjust that value, but could not find one.

Is there a way to send the command to keep the number of lines per page at 66?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your LPI value, see user's manual p. 184:

> **Control Code 06**
>
> Control Code 06 defines the function of ASCII code X'06' (ACK). You can select an
>   alternate line spacing of:
>
> · 8.0 LPI (the default)
>
> · 10.3 LPI
>
> · 6.0 LPI

Comment: That does look like what I'll need. But do I specify that in the PPD file? If so, where and what command do I issue? I can pipe everything to it via a TCP command, but would rather not.

Comment: Well, a PPD just defines the printer's capabilities, configuration is not its job. Happy piping!

Comment: So I was running a few test and the lines per inch is still the same. My configuration is still default (as stated on page 26 of the User Manual). What is changing is the "Forms Length In Lines". It for some reason is changing from the default 66 lines to 49 lines. Verified by printing out the current configuration page on the printer.

Comment: Let me give a little more information. On Page 157 of the user manual it states that the Form Length is the LPI x Form height. In my case the LPI is 6 and the Form length is 11 inches, which should be 66 lines, but some how it is only showing up as 49.

Comment: I suppose the AS/400 application is sending the Control Code 06. A hint 6/8 ≈ 49/66

Comment: I'm not sure if it is. When I print to it, it is changed to 49 lines, if the AS/400 prints to it right after me, it is still 49 lines (and the form is messed up after that). I have to power the device off then back on for it to reset and the AS/400 prints fine. I attempted to pipe the X'06' command to the printer with no success. It literally prints out X'06'

Comment: Of course you have to use raw printing, for example `lpr -l`. You know, X'06' is one character.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware it is one character. It's like pressing ctrl + F [ASCII commands](http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php) I've attempted to telnet into the printer and issue commands, even echo the commands and the stream to netcat like I've done for some other printers with no success. I appreciate the feedback and will explore other possibilities.

Comment: I see, CUPS should help you, take a look at https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-390@vm.marist.edu/msg58131.html